# Vault: init container cannot authenticate to Vault

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

I am deploying Hashicorp Vault and want to inject Vault Secrets into our Kubernetes Pods via Vault Agent Containers. At the moment it doesn't work and I am stuck when the Vault init container tries to connect to Vault with Kubernetes auth method:

```
$ kubectl logs mypod-d86fc79d8-hj5vv -c vault-agent-init -f
==> Note: Vault Agent version does not match Vault server version. Vault Agent version: 1.13.1, Vault server version: 1.13.2                                                                                                                  
==> Vault Agent started! Log data will stream in below:                                                                
                                                                                                                       
==> Vault Agent configuration:                                                                                         
                                                                                                                       
           Api Address 1: http://bufconn                                                                               
                     Cgo: disabled                                                                                     
               Log Level: info                                                                                         
                 Version: Vault v1.13.1, built 2023-03-23T12:51:35Z                                                                                                                                                                           
             Version Sha: 4472e4a3fbcc984b7e3dc48f5a8283f3efe6f282                                                     
                                                                                                                       
2023-06-22T15:01:43.754Z [INFO]  agent.sink.file: creating file sink                                                   
2023-06-22T15:01:43.754Z [INFO]  agent.sink.file: file sink configured: path=/home/vault/.vault-token mode=-rw-r-----  
2023-06-22T15:01:43.754Z [INFO]  agent.template.server: starting template server                                       
2023-06-22T15:01:43.754Z [INFO]  agent.auth.handler: starting auth handler                                             
2023-06-22T15:01:43.754Z [INFO]  agent.auth.handler: authenticating                                                    
2023-06-22T15:01:43.754Z [INFO] (runner) creating new runner (dry: false, once: false)                                 
2023-06-22T15:01:43.754Z [INFO]  agent.sink.server: starting sink server                                               
2023-06-22T15:01:43.755Z [INFO] (runner) creating watcher                                                              
2023-06-22T15:01:43.770Z [ERROR] agent.auth.handler: error authenticating:                                             
  error=                                                                                                               
  | Error making API request.                                                                                          
  |                                                                                                                    
  | URL: PUT https://vault.REDACTED.net:8200/v1/auth/kubernetes/login                                         
  | Code: 403. Errors:                                                                                                 
  |                                                                                                                    
  | * permission denied
```

I have followed two tutorials from Hashicorp ([here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/kubernetes/kubernetes-sidecar) and [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/kubernetes/kubernetes-external-vault#install-the-vault-helm-chart-configured-to-address-an-external-vault)).

## My infrastructure

- Vault is installed on AWS EC2
- EKS (1.23) cluster which contains namespace for each env and a namespace for Vault-injector

## What I did

1. Installed Vault injector in EKS:

```
 resource "helm_release" "vault_injector" {
   repository = "https://helm.releases.hashicorp.com"
   chart = "vault"
   version = local.settings.vault-injector.version
   name = "vault-injector"
   create_namespace = true
   namespace = "vault"
 
   set {
     name = "global.externalVaultAddr"
     value = local.settings.vault-injector.address
   }
 }
```

Result:

```
$ k get pods -n vault
NAME                                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
vault-injector-agent-injector-78b9c97bc9-tnjbj   1/1     Running   0          2d5h

$ k get sa -n vault
NAME                            SECRETS   AGE
default                         1         2d5h
vault-injector                  1         2d5h
vault-injector-agent-injector   1         2d5h
```

2. Following the tutorials, my next step was to configure Kubernetes authentication.

```
$ VAULT_HELM_SECRET_NAME=$(kubectl get secrets --output=json | jq -r '.items[].metadata | select(.name|startswith("vault-injector-token-")).name')

$ TOKEN_REVIEW_JWT=$(kubectl get secret $VAULT_HELM_SECRET_NAME --output='go-template={{ .data.token }}' | base64 --decode)

$ KUBE_CA_CERT=$(kubectl config view --raw --minify --flatten --output='jsonpath={.clusters[].cluster.certificate-authority-data}' | base64 --decode)

$ KUBE_HOST=$(kubectl config view --raw --minify --flatten --output='jsonpath={.clusters[].cluster.server}')

$ KUBE_ISSUER=$(kubectl get --raw /.well-known/openid-configuration | jq -r .issuer)

$ vault write auth/kubernetes/config \
     token_reviewer_jwt="$TOKEN_REVIEW_JWT" \
     kubernetes_host="$KUBE_HOST" \
     kubernetes_ca_cert="$KUBE_CA_CERT" \
     issuer="$KUBE_ISSUER"
```

3. I created a policy and a role for my deployment (service-copper):

```
$ vault policy write service-copper - <<EOF
path "apps/env/service-copper" {
  capabilities = ["read"]
}
EOF

$ vault write auth/kubernetes/role/service-copper \
     bound_service_account_names=copper \
     bound_service_account_namespaces=env \
     policies=service-copper \
     ttl=24h
```

4. At the point, I had to switch between tutorials to learn that I have to create a new Service Account (the one gave in `bound_service_account_names`)

```
$ kubectl create sa copper
```

5. I updated my deployment to add the service account

```
$ kubectl edit deployment service-copper
...
      spec:
      serviceAccountName: copper
      containers:
...
```

At the restart of the pods, I got the following error:

```
2023-06-22T16:51:43.996+0200  WARN [,7494923433757325112,3984854980495805192] 7 --- [qtp833308761-45] o.s.c.k.f.Fabric8PodUtils                : Failed to get pod with name:[service-copper-68c4444d8f-rj4ld]. You should look into this
 if things aren't working as you expect. Are you missing serviceaccount permissions?                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: GET at: https://172.20.0.1/api/v1/namespaces/env/pods/service-copper-68c4444d8f-rj4ld. Message: Forbidden!Configured service account doesn't have access. 
Service account may have been revoked. pods "service-copper-68c4444d8f-rj4ld" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:env:copper" cannot get resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "env".
```

That's the moment I learnt about `ClusterRoleBindings`. So I created one:

```bash
$ kubectl create clusterrolebinding copper-role --clusterrole=view --serviceaccount=env:copper --namespace=copper
```

6. I created a secret in `apps/env/service-copper` in Vault
7. I tried to inject secrets into the pod with an update of the deployment:

```
         vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: 'true'
         vault.hashicorp.com/role: 'service-copper'
         vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-copper.yaml: 'apps/env/service-copper'
```

Once the deployment is patched, the Init container starts and we arrive at the error:

```
[ERROR] agent.auth.handler: error authenticating:                                             
  error=                                                                                                               
  | Error making API request.                                                                                          
  |                                                                                                                    
  | URL: PUT https://vault.REDACTED.net:8200/v1/auth/kubernetes/login                                         
  | Code: 403. Errors:                                                                                                 
  |                                                                                                                    
  | * permission denied
```

## Question

Since I mixed tutorial, I am pretty sure I got lost on the way. I am a bit confused about the different service accounts and I feel like it is where the issue is.

Can you help me see a bit clearer on the subject? Thank you